# Edit Shape on Locked Layer with VBS [Visio]

Tags: vba, vbscript, visio

I place version numbers as a shape on a locked layer in my Visio pages and need to update a bunch of them programmatically. The solution seems simple for layer `Locked` and shape `VersionID`:

```vb
Sub editShape()

ActivePage.Layers("Locked").CellsC(visLayerLock).FormulaU = "0"
ActivePage.Shapes("VersionID").Text = "v1.2.3.4"
ActivePage.Layers("Locked").CellsC(visLayerLock).FormulaU = "1"

End Sub
```

The above doesn't work. The individual lines work, but running the subroutine consistently gives a notice about the shape being protected and the text is unchanged. It seems like it's trying to execute these lines in parallel so it attempts to alter the shape text before the layer is actually unlocked.

I've tried a few things, such as

- assigning them variables and setting/unsetting them between each step
- housing each line in a subroutine and calling them in sequence
- adding a `for` loop in between to create a literal time delay

None of these things worked. What did work in Visio was adding a `DoEvents` line between unlocking the layer and editing the shape.

Here's my problem: I need this to run via VBScript, and `DoEvents` doesn't exist there.

Alternatively: How do I get the program to stop and execute all code up to that point prior to proceeding? Something like a message box might work, but that greatly hinders the automatic nature of it.

Comment: What DoEvents does is it yields control from VBA back to the host application so it can process a queue of backed up messages in that thread. In vbscript you don't have a host application, you create an instance of some other application to work with. What you need to do is trigger that application to refresh what it needs to - is there some select or activate method you can play around with to force the app to refresh? Alternatively you can use winapi calls to manually pump the message queue and mimic DoEvents. These "Heisenbugs" that disappear when debugging are very frustrating I know.

Comment: @Greedo thanks, that's really useful! I've never really understood what DoEvents did and you really cleared it up. I'll play around with selects and activates and see if I can come up with something. The odd thing is that I've regularly used this workflow of unlock layer > do stuff > relock layer and it's only in these simple cases where it fails.

Comment: @Vince Have you checked that the shape text is not protected? It may be nothing to do with layers.

Comment: @Paul Yes. The shape isn't protected. The 3 lines of code work when run individually.

Answer (score 0):

I found a what I think is a solution.
Instead of using the entire layer, you could use the shape protection options under the developer tab to protect a specific shape. You can then enable or disable it later via VBA just as you intended to do with the layer.

To enable the protection, in my case a text within a textbox:

- Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(4).CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowLock, visLockTextEdit).FormulaU = "1"

To Disable the protection:

- Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(4).CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowLock, visLockTextEdit).FormulaU = "1"

Info on Developer/Shape Protection:

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/prevent-or-allow-changes-to-shapes-e65decf4-0eed-4fd6-a7d9-b286abcbc7eb